# How to use Desktop2.DesktopEventLogging to register UWP/MSIX app?

Tags: event-log, msix

I am looking for additional information on using  Desktop2.DesktopEventLogging in the AppXManifest to register an app event log, but the documentation is not exceptionally helpful and I am not finding any example usage.

The reason to want to perform the registration via manifest would be that it does not require elevation to add in the new log (and UWP/MSIX apps install without elevation). This is better than my current code based registration in the app that forces me to request elevation.

The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop2-desktopeventlogging)
But doesn't really provide clear guidance.  For example,

- What form of "message file" is desired?  Man, XML, Compiled bin, or maybe something else?
- Is the "appname" really the name of the app, as in referenced in an Application element in the manifest, or is it really the name that will be used as the name of the event log and/or category?

I am hoping that someone has actually tried this and has a clue!